# Git Hub Pages not Deploying. (404)

Tags: github, github-pages

I am new to web-development. I am trying to just start off by deploying my 1 page website just to sort of see how it works.

I followed all of the steps that I saw on a tutorial and I just get a 404. (file not found) https://juteland.github.io

Here is my repo. https://github.com/Juteland/juteland.github.io

If someone is good at this and can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have added homepage in your package.json too

Comment: Sorry, this might sound really bad, but what does that mean. I don't have a package.json in my repo?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

https://juteland.github.io/Documents/WebDev%20/IsomodularWebsite/

You have page on above link. You don't have index.html page on that directory. Hence it is showing 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

There are two directories inside **juteland.github.io** as per your github link:

1. Desktop/IsomodularWebsite
2. Documents/WebDev /IsomodularWebsite

As I am able to see both the directories contain the same number of files and both are duplicates.

Try the following steps:

1. You delete one of them. (Let's say you delete Documents/WebDev /IsomodularWebsite)
2. Move all files of Desktop/IsomodularWebsite inside juteland.github.io directly and then delete Desktop/IsomodularWebsite also.

Answer (score 0):

It is really 404, because you don't have index.html or index.htm or something that is specified as the entry point as a webpage **in your repository root**.

Your webpage is [there](https://juteland.github.io/Documents/WebDev%20/IsomodularWebsite), https://juteland.github.io/Documents/WebDev%20/IsomodularWebsite, with "strange" long URL.

Why do you put your web page inside such a long and meaningless folder**s**?

Comment: I do not know. Sorry, I am just really new to this. How do I change what the site URL is?

Comment: @BrendanGainer no issue. It happens. See index.html or index.htm is considered as the entry point of any webpage. So you should keep your index.html page in the root directory only instead of Documents/WebDev directory.

Comment: @BrendanGainer wait a while. I am posting an answer that will help you in this regard.

Comment: @BrendanGainer Move all things to the repository's root directory.